# How to create a compound index with local field and reference field mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using Mongoose with MongoDB.

I would like to query based on a field in a schema, and a field in a referenced schema. Here is the Model schema I am querying.

```
let schema = mongoose.Schema({
    parent_facility : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Facility', required: true },
    thirdPartyId : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

Here is the query I would like to do:

```
const modelsFound = await Model.find({thirdPartyId: 'randomidhere', parent_facility.status: 'complete'}).exec();
```

How can I build an index for this?

EDIT:

This seems to work the way I want

```
schema.createIndex({thirdPartyId: 1, 'parent_facility.status': 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Model.index({'thirdPartyId': 1, 'parent_facility': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this does not index fields of the referenced model.